# What does using leapfrog integration accomplish in particle simulations?

Tags: java, physics, particle-system

I have been working on a particle simulation in Java, and I'm a bit confused about leapfrog integration.

I read that it "conserves energy" and took that to mean that my particles would no longer sling-shot off at absurd speeds when their separation distance is near zero. However it still happens. Am I misunderstanding the point of leapfrog integration or did I implement it wrong?

Here is what happens: http://screencast.com/t/UcMNxucKVwn

I don't see any difference in results between updating velocity based on force at current position alone versus an average.

I won't post my whole project unless I need to because it is pretty long. The simulation is run using a Java swing timer that just runs updatePosition and then updateVelocity on each body and then draws them all.

Here is the body class:

```
public class Body {
    private final double G = 100; // Gravity strength
    private double xPos, yPos;
    private double xVel, yVel;
    private double radius;
    private double mass;
    private double oldFx;
    private double oldFy;

    public Body(double xPos, double yPos, double xVel, double yVel, double radius) {
        this.xPos = xPos;
        this.yPos = yPos;
        this.xVel = xVel;
        this.yVel = yVel;
        this.radius = radius;
        this.mass = Math.PI * radius * radius;
        this.oldFx = 0;
        this.oldFy = 0;
    }
    void updatePosition() {
        xPos += xVel;
        yPos += yVel;
    }

    void updateVelocity(Body b) {
        double DT = BHMain.DT/1000.0; // Time step
        // Force on this body
        double dx = xPos - b.xPos;
        double dy = yPos - b.yPos;
        double r = Math.sqrt((dx*dx + dy*dy));

        double newF = - G * mass * b.mass / (r*r);
        double angle = Math.atan2(dy, dx);
        double newFx = newF*Math.cos(angle);
        double newFy = newF*Math.sin(angle);

        double Fx = (oldFx + newFx) / 2;
        double Fy = (oldFy + newFy) / 2;

        // Update velocity. a = F / m.  v = v0 + a*t
        xVel += DT * Fx / mass;
        yVel += DT * Fy / mass; 

        oldFx = newFx;
        oldFy = newFy;
    }
    void drawBody(Graphics g) {
        int diameter = (int) (2 * radius);
        int x = (int) (xPos - radius);
        int y = (int) (yPos - radius);
        g.fillOval(x, y, diameter, diameter);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to multiply the update of the position with the time step. `xPos += xVel*DT`. Try decreasing the time step, do 4 steps of 1/4 size between frames instead of one full step.

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot the DT in updating xPos. I fixed that but it only slows down the animation. I still have particles flying off erratically when they touch. What do you mean 4 steps? Wouldn't that be the same as doing 2 steps with half the time step, I'd still be leaping between force and position right?

Decreasing the time step just slows down the animation